# ¿Cómo centrar un GridView en Flutter?

Tags: flutter, gridview, dart

Busco hacer un pequeño menú de opciones con tarjetas, y para ello estoy usando un GridView.

Mi arbol de widgets es como sigue:

```
Center{

  Container{

    GridView{...}

  }

}
```

Cabe destacar que el Grid es llamado por el Container desde un método que creé aparte (para tener el código acomodado ), se los muestro a continuación

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold(

      appBar: AppBar(
        ...
        ...
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Container(    
          child: _cuadricula(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _cuadricula(context) {

    return  Align(

      child: GridView.count(
        children: _tarjetas()
      ),
    );
  }
```

**El problema** es que quiero que el GridView quede centrado en pantalla, (centrado en el container que muestro a continuación), y no es así!

Pensé que el Center que envuelve al Container le daría la propiedad también al Grid, pero no, solo afecta al Container, como pueden ver:

[image: El Center centra al Container, pero no al GridView]

Ya intenté:

- Poniendo un widget Center que envuelva al Grid.
- también intenté con el widget Align, pero no he logrado lo que busco.
- Igual con la propiedad Alignment del Container, pero tampoco.

Cualquier ayuda será agradecida! Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para centrar el `GridView` simplemente agrega `Center` como widget padre y también la propiedad `shrinkWrap` debe estar en true.

```dart
Center(
 child: GridView.count(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: _tarjetas()
      ),
)
```